# Mobile Me Family Pack Accounts: Do Sub-Accounts have their own syncing features?

Tags: data-synchronization, mobileme

Merry Christmas.

**In a MobileMe Family Pack, do the subaccounts have their own, independent syncing features (dock, bookmarks, etc - as seen in the MobileMe system preference?).**

I could really use the syncing features, but I don't need a full individual account. My brother has an individual account, and we were thinking of upgrading it to a family, so I could get the syncing features (I have a work mac, and a personal mac).

The [Apple Website](http://www.apple.com/mobileme/pricing/) is a little vague on this:

> A Family Pack subscription includes one Individual account with 20GB of combined email and file storage, plus four Family Member accounts, each with its own email address and 5GB of storage. Convert an Individual account to a Family Pack anytime you like — you just pay the difference.

I'm not sure whether to read it as 'a family pack is a glorified email account' or 'a family pack is a full mobile me account (with syncing features) but less space for each user'.

Comment: IIRC the Family Pack is 4 (5?) accounts, accounts being identified with a unique username/e-mail address. The sync should be able to take place uniquely per unique username/e-mail address. Not an answer because I don't know if I'm right and would rather format this better if it were an answer :). Anyone is free to steal my work if they cite their sources too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a family pack allows you to create 4 additional usernames that have all the features of the main account, the only difference being that they are limited to 5gb of storage.  I upgraded to a family pack and used one of the 4 additional accounts for my girlfriend so she could use Find My iPhone (before it was free with an AppleID) she can also sync her bookmarks, dock, prefs, etc just like my account.

The only thing I am not 100% sure is if she can also create alias email addresses like I can on my main account but I believe she can.